# android : convert color in `rgba()` to hex format

Tags: android, android-color

I have (unfortunately. Anyways..) color format which is used in html:

`rgba(31,194,174,1)`

I want to convert it to android native hex color format #AARRGGBB.
Can anyone please help me with this.

I tried the following way, but it didn't worked:

```
...
tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getTabLayoutBackgroundColor(jsonObject));
...

private int getTabLayoutBackgroundColor(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    // tab color
    String[] rgba_tab = new String[4];
    try {
        rgba_tab = jsonObject.getString("navbar-background-color").split("\\(")[1].split("\\)")[0].split(",");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Color.argb(Integer.parseInt(rgba_tab[3]), Integer.parseInt(rgba_tab[0]), Integer.parseInt(rgba_tab[1]), Integer.parseInt(rgba_tab[2]));
}
```

I have to parse the following response to set colors dynamically to my controls like ToolBar, TabLayout background and TabLayout text colors:

```
{
    "primary-color": "rgba(214,34,48,1)",
    "background-color": "default",
    "navbar-background-color": "rgba(214,34,48,1)",
    "navbar-font-color": "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    "font": "Arial"
}
```

Comment: Please note that html/css rgba uses float value between [0.0 - 1.0] for alpha. It doesn't map directly as an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x%02x", alpha,red, green, blue);
```

Comment: You mean to say, I should replace alpha, red, green, blue with my array elements, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    Color c = new Color(i,j,k);
    Integer.toHexString( c.getRGB() & 0x00ffffff ) );

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function to convert color from *rgba* to android color format:

```
@ColorInt
int parseRgba(@NonNull String colorString, @ColorInt int defaultColor) {
    String cs = colorString.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    if (cs.startsWith("rgba(") && cs.endsWith(")")) {
        String[] components = cs
                .substring(5, cs.length() - 1)
                .split(",");
        if (components.length == 4) {
            try {
                int red = Integer.parseInt(components[0]);
                int green = Integer.parseInt(components[1]);
                int blue = Integer.parseInt(components[2]);
                float alphaF = Float.parseFloat(components[3]);
                if (0 <= red && red <= 255 &&
                        0 <= green && green <= 255 &&
                        0 <= blue && blue <= 255 &&
                        0f <= alphaF && alphaF <= 1f) {
                    return Color.argb((int) (alphaF * 255), red, green, blue);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
    return defaultColor;
}
```